# Configuring kbdmap on FreeBSD for Meta+Left/Right key combinations

Tags: freebsd, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a FreeBSD 12.1 installation, and the problem is that on a [`syscons`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syscons&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) or [`vt`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vt&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports) virtual terminal (rather than, say, an XTerm emulated terminal), both the keys <kbd>← Left</kbd> and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>← Left</kbd> (and the same for <kbd>→ Right</kbd>) get mapped to the same escape sequence: `<ESC>[D` (I have verified this using the `showkey` utility).

However, this means that within the shell, <kbd>← Left</kbd> and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>← Left</kbd> perform the same actions (move left by one character), and no configuration of `.inputrc` can change that (so that <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>← Left</kbd> moves left a whole word).

Now, I believe that *kbdmap* can help solve this issue, but I have no idea how to correctly configure it. There seems to be some information [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/binding-ctrl-left-right-to-back-forward-word-outside-x.59815/), but it makes no sense to me whatsoever.